# variable & incomplete behavior "for" loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, range

I'm trying to loop on numbers between 44100000 to 44999999 in python.
I tried this:

```
f=open('of','w')
i=44100000
while i<=44999999 :
     f.write(str(i)+"\n")
     i+=1
```

but it is incomplete! the tail of the `of` file is:

```
44999750
44999751
44999752
44999753
449997
```

notice the last number that

1. is not the last number in the range
2. is incomplete! and has not the same length as the others!

when I did it again the same code gave me this tail of file:

```
44999993
44999994
44999995
44999996
44999997
44999998
```

and the third run made complete & correct out put:

```
44999994
44999995
44999996
44999997
44999998
44999999
```

while this worked correctly every time:

```
for i in range(44100000,44999999):
     f.write('%d\n' % (i,))
```

What is the problem? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you close the file?

Comment: or alternatively `flush()` the file buffer with `f.flush()`

Comment: Oh noooooooooooooooooooooo! it seems you're right; but why the `range` worked correctly every time? thanks

Comment: It is not interesting why it apparently worked correctly with `range`. It could be down to random chance. The best thing is to always close the file :)

Comment: I get the exact same result without closing the file. This must be due to the buffer size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You fail to close the file before terminating the process. It is good practice to use resources that need cleaning up in a `with` statement:

```
with open('of', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Stuff")

# f.close() will be called automatically upon leaving the with-scope
```